# How to get this transaction confirmed using the api

Tags: transaction, iota-network, reattach, promote

Need some help with a transaction. I'm trying to write my own wallet for learning purposes. I was able to get the PoW algorithm working in my local project and broadcast the transaction successfully for a transfer of 1iota. The transaction has been pending for almost a whole day, and I've tried promoting it and replaying it hundreds of times. I think I may be doing it wrong though. Can someone take a look at this transaction and tell me what I may have done wrong?

https://thetangle.org/transaction/LPYBCFJFOLLBAWTGJPBFJRLMVFYUAVKRRNTAY9ATVPLNYLXVGDMG9DFCWOSEHWQQQPVNXNKNAFKW99999

Comment: Looks like a reattachment confirmed meanwhile. So the bundle itself was okay. Only idea I have is that you were unlucky with picking your tips...

Comment: Did you solved it? It seems it is reattached now.

Comment: @wonglik I didn't do anything but it seems to have resolved itself. Based on responses from the community on reddit it seems the day I attempted this was a day the network was performing poorly, and once it sorted itself out my transaction confirmed.